# ionic run code to create databse only once

Tags: ionic-framework

I created an app using ionic, and in the app I want to create and populate a database, but I want the code to run once, not everytime I open the app. Because once the databace is create for first time,  no need to run recreate it again.

I googled it, I did not find an answer, 
I appreciate any one has a solution.

```
private dboptions: any = {
    name: 'ba.db',
    createFromLocation: 1,
    location: 'default'
  }
constructor(
    private sqlite: SQLite) {

    this.connectDB();

  }

  private connectDB(): any {
    this.sqlite.create(this.dboptions).then(
      (db: SQLiteObject) => {

        // create the table
        let sql = `CREATE TABLE ba ( 
          id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
          name      VARCHAR (200)  NOT NULL UNIQUE,
          title     VARCHAR (200)`;
        db.executeSql(sql, []).then(success => {
          console.log('table created');

        }).catch(err => {
          console.log(err);

        })

      }
    )
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }
```

Comment: Can you show us how you create the database?

Comment: @SalmanUllah, add edited the post and added the code. 
My point is how run a piece of code only once in ionic app, just when the app is run for the first time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User LocalStorage to check if DB is already created like this. [Storage](https://ionicframework.com/docs/storage/) Here is the link on how to add local storage to your project.

```
private dboptions: any = {
  name: 'ba.db',
  createFromLocation: 1,
  location: 'default'
}
constructor(
  private sqlite: SQLite, , public storage: Storage) {

  this.storage.get("isDbPresent")
    .then((data) => {
      console.log(data);
      if (data === null) {
        this.connectDB();
        this.storage.get(Constants.storagekey)
      }
    })


}

private connectDB(): any {
   this.sqlite.create(this.dboptions).then(
    (db: SQLiteObject) => {

      // create the table
      let sql = `CREATE TABLE ba ( 
        id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
        name      VARCHAR (200)  NOT NULL UNIQUE,
        title     VARCHAR (200)`;
      db.executeSql(sql, []).then(success => {
        console.log('table created');

      }).catch(err => {
         console.log(err);

      })

    }
  )
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add ionic Storage and save a flag when done.

in app.module.ts

```
import { IonicStorageModule } from '@ionic/storage';

...
imports: [
   ...
   IonicStorageModule.forRoot()
],
...
```

in your component/provider

```
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';

storage.ready().then(() => {
  storage.get('notFirstTime').then((notFirstTime:boolean) => {
    if (!notFirstTime){
      // Do what you want to do once
    }
    storage.set('notFirstTime', true);
  })
});
...
```

ionic storage is persistent (when you install `cordova-sqlite-storage`plugin)